# Heinz integral formula in the degree theory

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology

> The following problems can be found in chapter 8 of the PDE book by Evans. Here $U$ is an open, bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary. After problem 4, I was asked to solve problem 5. To take the first step, one can consider $x_0$ to be a regular value of $\mathbf{u}$. And, by employing the inverse function theorem, one can show that
>   $$\deg(\mathbf{u},x_0)=\sum_{\mathbf{u}^{-1}(\{x_0\})}\mathrm{sgn}(\det D\mathbf{u}(x)),$$
>   upon using integration by substitution as below. Note that this is a finite sum. Next we have to consider the general case in which $x_0$ may not be regular. It's desirable to use Sard's theorem, from which we conclude that regular values constitute a dense set. Thus, we are able to find a sequence of regular values that converges to $x_0$. But what's next? Is there any theorem to guarantee that the sequential limit exists? I need someone to help me out. Please. Thank you very much.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach here is to invoke Sard's theorem. First do the proof assuming that the Jacobian does not vanish at any point $y\in U$ with $\mathbf{u}(y) = x_0$. The set of $x_0$ for which this holds is called the set of regular values of $\mathbf{u}$, and Sard's theorem says that the regular values of $\mathbf{u}$ are dense in the image of $\mathbf{u}$. So once you have the result for regular values, you can recover the result for non-regular values by a limiting argument, as the limit of an integer sequence is an integer.

Comment: Thank you. But I still can't figure it out. Is it better for me to start with the simplest case that $x_0$ is a regular value of $\mathbf{u}$?

Comment: Yes, you should start with that case. Note that the preimage of a regular value of $\mathbf{u}$ is finite, since $\mathbf{u}$ has bounded domain. This means that if you choose $r$ small enough in the definition of $\eta$, then the domain of integration will break up into several disjoint small pieces, which are neighborhoods of the points of the preimage of $x_0$. By choosing $r$ small enough, you can guarantee that $\operatorname{sgn}\det Du$ is constant on these neighborhoods, and pull it out as a common factor. Then use change of variables and that $\eta$ integrates to $1$ to conclude.

Comment: What if $\mathbf{u}^{-1}(\{x_0\})$ is empty in this simple case?

Comment: Then the integral is $0$ for small enough $r$, because then by continuity, there exists a ball $B$ around $x_0$ such that $\mathbf{u}(y)$ does not take values in that ball. If we take $r$ so that $B(x_0,r)$ is contained in $B$, then $\mathbf{u}(y)$ is outside of $B$, and therefore outside of $B(x_0,r)$, and therefore outside the support of $\eta$. Therefore $\eta(\mathbf{u}(y))$ is zero.

Comment: How do you find such $B$ by continuity? Since $x_0$ is outside of $\mathbf{u}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, can we find $B$ by considering the topological property of the codomain $\mathbb{R}^n$? Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to construct it, one exists directly as a consequence of continuity. If $\mathbf{u}$ does not take the value $x_0$, there must exist a ball $B$ around $x_0$ so that $\mathbf{u}$ does not take values in $B$; for suppose no such ball exists. Then for every $r>0$, I can find a point $x_r\in B(x_0,r)$ such that $\mathbf{u}$ takes the value $x_r$. But then taking $r\to 0$, by continuity $\mathbf{u}$ must also take the value $x_0$.

Comment: Could you explain why $B(x_0,r)\cap\mathbf{u}(\partial U)=\emptyset$? Thank you.

Comment: Without that condition, the domain of integration will contain neighborhoods of points in $\partial U$. This is a problem because while the sign of $\det Du$ is constant on small neighborhoods of interior points of $U$, the same is not true at the boundary. Then the proof outline given above falls apart. You could, for instance, imagine a $C^1$ function whose derivative is nonsingular everywhere within $U$, but is singular on $\partial U$.

Comment: Thank you. Now I would like to deal with the general case by passing to limits. I think your argument is something like the update to the question, but I'm worried about the existence of the limit.